# How can I analyse special kind of contraints in C# using reflection?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Please see the following code:

```
public class GenericTest2
{

    public class MyGenericClass<T, U, V, W>
        where T : class
        where U : new()
        where V : struct
        where W : System.IO.StringWriter
    {
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        Assembly a = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(GenericTest));
        foreach (Type t in a.GetTypes()) {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(t.FullName);
            if (t.IsGenericType) {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("\tIsGeneric!");
                foreach (Type parm in t.GetGenericArguments()) {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("\tGeneric parameter: " + parm.Name);
                    Type[] constraints = parm.GetGenericParameterConstraints();
                    for (int i = 0; i < constraints.Length; i++) {
                        Console.Out.WriteLine("\t\t constraint " + i + ": name = " + constraints[i].Name);
                        Console.Out.WriteLine("\t\t constraint " + i + ": fullname = " + constraints[i].FullName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This code will output something like this:

```
ProcessCSharpAssemblies.Program
ProcessCSharpAssemblies.GenericTest2
ProcessCSharpAssemblies.GenericTest2+MyGenericClass`4
    IsGeneric!
    Generic parameter: T
    Generic parameter: U
    Generic parameter: V
        constraint 0: name = ValueType
        constraint 0: fullname = System.ValueType
    Generic parameter: W
        constraint 0: name = StringWriter
        constraint 0: fullname = System.IO.StringWriter
```

The constraints `class` and `new()` do not seem to be returned by `parm.GetGenericParameterConstraints()`. Though there are constraints for `T` and `U` `parm.GetGenericParameterConstraints()` does not return data.

Q: How can I check for these kind of constraints using reflection?

Answer (score 4):

The constraints you are looking for can be found by looking into the [GenericParameterAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.type.genericparameterattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) of a `Type`.

```
var gpa = parm.GenericParameterAttributes;

var constraints = gpa & GenericParameterAttributes.SpecialConstraintMask;

if ((constraints & GenericParameterAttributes.DefaultConstructorConstraint) != 0)
{
    // yippie!
}
```